# How to find largest sum value based on budget

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with 3 columns (Name, Value, Cost). I am trying to find a way to return 15 Names from the data set that provide the highest Value with a combined Cost of $200 or less.

Ideally, I'd like to return say the top 20 unique entries of the combination of 15 Names that provide the highest combined Value.

Example Data Set:

| Name | Value | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | $15 | $7 |
| Jill | $20 | $9 |

Comment: Is this Python or R?

Comment: Python is not R is not Excel. Which of the 3 are you actually using?

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    arrange(desc(readr::parse_number(Cost))) %>%
    filter(cumsum(readr::parse_number(Cost)) <=200)
```

Comment: @tdwalter13 I am assuming that your column is `factor` instead of `character`.  then change to code to `parse_number(as.character(Cost))`

Comment: Thank you, I don't actually have "$" in my data set so I don't think I need the "readr::parse_number" in here. Without it, I was able to return a tibble, but it's missing the element of needing 15 Names. Currently it only returns the top 3 Names as adding the 4th name puts me over the $200 budget in the Cost column.